# Type.GetConstructor returns null and Type.GetConstructors is empty

Tags: c#, xamarin, system.reflection, c#-9.0, .net-standard-2.1

First, this is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20120210/type-getconstructor-returns-null-on-iphone) as I am Linking everything and It keeps not working.
The problem occurs on a Xamarin.Forms App, I am passing a Type that extends a .NetStandard abstract class to be able to invoke a native implementation by the Xamarin.Forms common project.
At this time the project can't find any constructor of the type.
If I use GetConstructor with the right types it will return null.
If I use GetConstructors it will return an empty list.

Is anyone able to tell me how can I make the project able to find the constructor and why It's not working at the moment?

Please take note, "Use the DependencyService" is not an answer since It will not cover the questions I made.
I want to know the reason why It's not working and how to use this functionality, not any other alternative.

By the way. I had a project where It worked but to my eyes, there were no differences except the Native target platform OS version and the Xamarin.Forms version.

Comment: Can you add some minimal reproducible code - perhaps a very basic .NET Standard abstract class, a simple class that extends it (with a constructor), and a method running within the Xamarin.Forms app that is calling `GetConstructors` on the type? Otherwise, it's rather difficult to recreate your setup

Comment: Also, are you able to call `GetConstructors()` on any other type? Say, if you add a class directly to your Xamarin.Forms project (which does not extend any outside classes) - does that work?